# Multipart/Mixed in Spring Boot 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, multipart

i've got problems create an endpoint in Spring Boot, which accepts Multipart/Mixed. The http request doesn't seem to even reach the controller. I tried the following http request in a new Spring Boot Project (v.2.7.0):

---

Edit (Changed Code): I made a new Project with the following Code, as M. Deinum suggested:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MultiparttestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultiparttestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setStrictServletCompliance(true);
        multipartResolver.setResolveLazily(true);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MultipartTest {

    @PostMapping(path="multipartTest", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> multipart(@RequestPart User user) {
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

The Request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/multipartTest
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=WebAppBoundary

--WebAppBoundary
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Heidi"
}

--WebAppBoundary--
```

But I still get the same error:

```
2022-06-02 11:59:07.551 ERROR 13852 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly] with root cause

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:520) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:243) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:142) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:276) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2932) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:72) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.asMultipartHttpServletRequest(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.<init>(RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.java:68) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Any help or hints would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: Disable file uploading, which by default will parse the multipart request.

Comment: Hey but I want also to use a controller with MultipartFile. How do I do that without file uploading? If I disable it spring boot wants me to specificy a configuration to process the parts of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly configure the `StandardServletMultipartResolver` to be aligned strictly with the servlet spec. Which means it will only parse `multipart/form-data` and leaves everything else untouched. By default this property is set to `false`.

To enable add a bean to configure this.

```java
@Bean(name = DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver(MultipartProperties multipartProperties) {
  StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
  multipartResolver.setStrictServletCompliance(true);
  multipartResolver.setResolveLazily(multipartProperties.isResolveLazily());
  return multipartResolver;
}
```

This will now let the `StandardServletMultipartResolver` parse `multipart/form-data` and leave all other `multipart/*` stuff alone for handling in the controller.

Comment: Thanks. But I get still the same error stack as described in my initial post. I enabled multipart servlet in application properties and registered the bean with setStrictServletCompliance(true).

Comment: Why did you enable the servlet?! I'm now unsure what you have done. You should only register this bean, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Hi removed any properties but I still get the same error with the new bean. If I debug the error, I see that readHeaders is looking for \r\n to read the headers, but the request only has \n, without carriage return. Its really weird. Seems like a bug? To be mentioned: multipart/form-data is working.

Comment: I doubt it is the same error, as this one comes from the `StandardServletMultipartResolver ` which should now only trigger on `multipart/form-data`. Hence I doubt it is the same exception, or at least the same origin.

Comment: I edited my initial post with the new code. Can u check what I did wrong there? Thank you!

Comment: As I stated it is **not** the same error. If you compare the stacktraces you will clearly see they are different. So it is **not** the same error. It now actually tries to parse the parts and pass them to your method, it is now the parsing that fails.

Comment: Ye I noticed that too, but why does the parsing fail? My controller and request seems to be correct?

Comment: It isn't the controller tomcat fails on parsing, how is the request being send. Also please restore the initial question as that has been resolved, you now run into another issue (which should be in a different question imho). Looking at the documentation the header should have \r\n and not only \n. Are you on windows and how are you generating the request?

Comment: I tried to send Http Request with ReadyAPI and IntelliJ with .http scratch file (under Windows). Both are not working. Also a different Applications with Multipart/Mixed have been deployed on Linux with the same issue.

Comment: It isn't the server that is the problem it is the client... Your .scratch file should have the proper line endings else it will fail.

Comment: curl -X POST --location "http://localhost:8080/multipartTest" \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=WebAppBoundary" \
    -d "--WebAppBoundary
Content-Type: application/json

{
  \"name\": \"Heidi\"
}

--WebAppBoundary--"

Comment: See above comment: Is this not ok? I never had to paste \r\n manually for that.

Comment: It is the request that is being generated that is wrong, I suspect it used the platform to determine the line-ending instead of the ones needed per spec.

Comment: I paste \r\n manually in the request:
`curl -X POST --location "http://localhost:8080/multipartTest" -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=WebAppBoundary" -d "--WebAppBoundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{\r\n\"name\": \"Heidi\"\r\n}\r\n--WebAppBoundary--\r\n\r\n"`


But now I get this (I tried using value or/and name attribute): Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'user' is not present]

Comment: Judging from what you posted, in that snippet there is no part named `user`. But the fact that it returns a different error, means it now reaches the controller. Which means the request passes and the solution works, and thus your request was the thing that was also part of the problem/error.